# Mongoose not $setting array.$.booleanValue when I findOneAndUpdate({paramOne: p, paramTwo, array.keyName: valueName})

Tags: express, mongoose, postman

I'm trying to update a boolean value in an object that's in an array in a mongo document with mongoose through an

```
 app.post("/api/post/:chorecomplete", function(req, res){
            Parent.findOneAndUpdate({parentFirstName: req.body.parentFirstName, parentLastName: req.body.parentLastName, "chores.choreName": "firstChore"}, {$set: {"chores.$.complete": "true"}}).exec(function(err, doc){
                if (err){ console.log(err); res.send("not ok");}
                    else{
                        console.log(doc);`enter code here`
                        res.send(ok);
                    }
            })
        })

    }
```

My server logs the mongoose response, but not because I'm telling it too. I commented out the console.log(doc) and it tested it to see if my db was returning it or my server was logging it. Thing is, my server responds with "Ok" meaning mongoose is not throwing an error, but it isn't modifying my 

     `POST /api/post/chorecomplete 200 17.378 ms - 2
    [1] { _id: 597aa48313cf6914905916e0,
    [1]   parentFirstName: 'firstName',
    [1]   parentLastName: 'lastName',
    [1]   parentEmail: 'mich@ael.com',
    [1]   __v: 0,
    [1]   children: [],
    [1]   chores:
    [1]    [ { choreName: 'firstChore',
    [1]        choreDesc: 'firstDescription',
    [1]        value: null,
    [1]        complete: false },
    [1]      { choreName: 'secondChore',
    [1]        choreDesc: 'secondDescription',
    [1]        choreValue: null,
    [1]        complete: false }] }`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've got a static query parameter in there, but"firstChore" will eventually be req.body.choreName. I'm beginning to wonder if I should make a collection for chores and ref it to my Parent and Child Schemas, but I'm not 100% sure how to go about implementing a reference to Parent and Child which will ref each other... (Parent and Child will both have separate user accounts, Child will update a chore to be completed and will receive the choreValue [which is supposed to be $5.00 in this example, but for some reason mongoose doesn't accept it. It's not currently defined anywhere except form values.]). This is an example Schema. (I'm trying to be as detailed as possible. It's late and this is my first question here.)

```//Parent Schema
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ParentSchema = new Schema({
    parentFirstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

```
parentLastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

parentEmail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: [
    function(input){
        input.length >= 3;
    },
    "Email must be a valid email"
    ]
},

password: {
type: String,
//required: true,
validate: [
    function(input){
        input.length >= 6;
    },
    "Password must be at least 6 characters"
    ]
},

chores: { 
    type: Array,
},

children: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Child"
}]
```

});

var Parent = mongoose.model("Parent", ParentSchema);

module.exports = Parent;

## ```

This is the route for adding a chore to the array. It will be form values. A chore is effectively defined on the fly in this route as opposed to explicitly defined as it's own model.

`//route for inserting chores
app.post("/api/post/:chores", function(req, res){
    //When we have someone logged in we will take one of the values we get from their presence, (either _id or email) and replace my name. It's only my name b/c it was the name I initially inserted into the db.
    //if chores === chores then findAll else if {var theChoreToFind === req.params.chores} and we'll run that chore to update a chore?
    var parentFirstName = req.body.parentFirstName;
    var parentLastName = req.body.parentLastName;
    var choreName = req.body.choreName;
    var choreDesc = req.body.choreDesc;
    var choreValue = req.body.choreValue;
    Parent.findOneAndUpdate({parentFirstName: req.body.parentFirstName, parentLastName: req.body.parentLastName}, {$push: {chores: {choreName: choreName, choreDesc: choreDesc, choreValue: choreValue, complete: false}}}).exec(function(err, doc){
        if(err) {console.log(err)}
        console.log(doc);
    })
    res.send("Ok");
})//END new Chores`

This is incredibly long winded. I just didn't want to have anything I brought up to not be here for reference. If you've made it this far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Possible Issue

This looks like it may be an issue with your Express routes rather than MongoDB.

The rest of your code looks valid, but you have one `post` route named `/api/post/:chores` and another route name `/api/post/:chorecomplete`

Though the parameter names are different Express will actually interpret these routes as identical since the colon makes the parameter a wildcard which can be any value you pass to it.

In Express, the order in which properties are attached to `app` is very important.

In this situation, assuming you don't have any other `post` routes that match the `/api/post/:parameter` pattern, if `/api/post/:chores` is written before `/api/post/:chorecomplete` then any post request to `/api/post/:chorecomplete` will actually match `/api/post/:chores` and run the code you have in that route.

This is probably the reason you're getting an `OK` response and the console is 
logging a document from the DB, because you're actually posting to `/api/post/:chores`and running a successful query.

#### Solution

There are a few ways you could address this, all which revolve around changing the path of the route. It all depends on your naming pattern and how you plan to access the data.

Since the code in question is updating an existing document you could make it a `put` route instead

```js
 app.put("/api/post/:chorecomplete", function(req, res) {...}
```

Or you could keep it as `post` and append another name to the path so that it no longer matches another route in your code:

```js
 app.post("/api/post/chorecomplete/:parameter", function(req, res) {...}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that... I seriously thought it had to do with my mongoose syntax, but this explains it. Thank you!!